# Adding SeriesCollection to a Chart with UserForm (combobox)

Tags: excel, vba, charts, userform, excel-2016

I am learning to use VBA for excel in Excel 2016. At the moment I am working through an assignment on this website: http://www.homeandlearn.org/vba_charts_and_user_forms.html in which I want to show a scatter-plot of one of the football teams' results. This is done by selecting the team with a combobox in a user form.

The result of the code (see below) ought to be a scatterplot with One line and a title, like this:
http://www.homeandlearn.org/images/vba_charts/chart_arsenal.gif (cannot upload it for some reason)

However, this is the result of my code.

[image]

**How is it possible that, with the exact same code as on the website, the Chart isn't able to show the selected data and title?** I also wonder where the fifth series came from, since I only have four columns.

The code is as follows (and unique to the code described on the website):

```
Private Sub cmdLoad_Click()
    If cbSelect.Text = "Select a chart" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a chart"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim ChartData As Range
    Dim ChartIndex As Integer
    Dim ChartName As String

    ChartIndex = cbSelect.ListIndex

    Select Case ChartIndex
        Case 0
            Set ChartData = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B20")
            ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
        Case 1
            Set ChartData = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C20")
            ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value
        Case 2
            Set ChartData = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D20")
            ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value
        Case 3
            Set ChartData = ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E20")
            ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value
    End Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart

    MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName
    MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartData
    MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20")

    'Save chart as an image, remove the chart, then set updating screen to ON'
    Dim imageName As String
    imageName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\gs16_pictures" & Application.PathSeparator & "TempChart.gif"
    MyChart.Export Filename:=imageName, FilterName:="GIF"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Load picture in user form
    UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)
```

cbSelect is initialized as follows

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cbSelect.AddItem Range("B1") 'Arsenal
    cbSelect.AddItem Range("C1") 'Man City
    cbSelect.AddItem Range("D1") 'Newcastle
    cbSelect.AddItem Range("E1") 'Cardiff
    cbSelect.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the statement

```
Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart
```

This statement automatically plotted the entire data table. To prevent it, it was necessary to explicitly state the SourceData. Below is the code which you need instead of the lines starting with `MyChart.SeriesCollection`

```
With MyChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=ChartData
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = ChartName
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A20")

End With
```

I am not sure why there is a difference between Excel 2016 and the example from the website. Perhaps Excel is "smarter" than before and interpreted the source data.